# Need help for this circuit

Tags: circuit-analysis

For the sake of simplicity, I extracted part of my circuit to get the following simulation circuit.

[image]

I measure the potential of the base of Q1.

[image]

Why is it -7 V? Shouldn't it be 0 V?

Comment: Explain why you think it should be at 0. What are your .ic initial conditions? Does your 2N2222 model have the reverse BE breakdown behaviour, and if so, with what characteristic. If EB is open circuit, what would you expect a -7 V power supply to take the base to, connected as it is with a 'large' capacitor?

Comment: Since there is no loop to charge the capacitor, I think the capacitor acts as a break in the circuit. Then I think the potential of b can be measured after removing the capacitor. At this time, the potential of b should be the same potential as the ground?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The simulation shows -7 V on the transistor base because you have **uic** in your **.tran** command. This skips the initial operating point solution, which is how LTspice finds the DC operating point of the circuit.

Uncheck that box in the simulation command settings and you'll see 0 V on the base.

Comment: Thanks for help! It did work! But I don't understand. I found that after checking this box named skip the initial operating point solution , there will be a current from bottom to top. Why does it happen?

Comment: @TL How big is "a current"?

Comment: Sir, the peak value of the current is about 61 mA. The direction is from bottom to top.

Comment: @TL That's a very short peak due to the parasitic capacitor in the BJT being changed. The steady state current is zero.